# Running multiple independent Node programs in the same Node instance

Tags: node.js, memory, limit, microcontroller

I'm doing embedded development on a resource-limited system, and need to run a number of separate Node.js tasks (call them `task1.js`, `task2.js` and `task3.js`). The obvious solution would be to run them separately, e.g.:

```
$ node task1.js &
[1] 1968
$ node task2.js &
[2] 1969
$ node task3.js &
[3] 1970
$
```

This works, but I end up with three independent Node stacks, each with its own multi-megabyte heap, interpreter, etc. etc. etc., which is a waste that I'd like to avoid.

Another obvious solution would be to concatenate the source files:

```
$ cat task1.js task2.js task3.js | node -
```

This works, but it has problems. First, all three task sources would end up in the same module, so I'd risk name collisions. For example, if each task file included `const crypto = require('crypto');`, then when concatenated Node would complain about the multiply-defined `crypto` variable.

This would also require all of the primary task source files to be in the same directory, otherwise any relative path references to dependent files would be calculated based on the default working directory, and would likely break.

So, I'm looking for a way to run multiple tasks in the same Node instance, sharing Node resources as much as possible.

It would be great if some or all the following were true:

- For development/debugging convenience, the same `taskX.js` sources could be used individually (as at the top), or run at the same time in the same node instance
- No special care would have to be made in each task's code to prevent namespace collisions
- Relative path references in `include` statements wouldn't all be resolved from the same working directory, so that I could have separate source trees for the separate tasks

Problems I don't need to be solved:

- Multiprocessing or multithreading
- Sharing data between the tasks
- Inter-task events and communication services (if I do I'll write them myself)
- Protecting each task from the others' bad behavior

Expected constraints for the task code:

- No busy-waiting, so that none block the others from executing
- No exclusive use of common system resources (e.g. no two will open a server socket on the same port)
- Use of global Node resources will be restricted or forbidden

Comment: Did you try child_process?

Comment: @estus From the doc: "Each process has its own memory, with their own V8 instances." So, that wouldn't help me, but thanks.

Comment: You can check experimental worker threads then. *I'd risk name collisions (e.g. I couldn't have const crypto = require('crypto'); in multiple task sources). It also requires all primary task source files to be in the same directory, otherwise their relative path references to dependent files would break.* - what's the meaning of this? `const` is in module scope, there shouldn't be name collisions.  Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , this totally depends on your specific case whether it's possible and how. Basically you could try to do `require('./task1'); require('./task2')`

Comment: @estus Thanks; I've added some details to my concerns about name collisions and relative paths. And, your last sentence sounds like an answer; I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @estus Bingo: that's the answer: many thanks. Do you want to post it, or should I?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I don't consider it a good answer in general that can help other readers because it's really dependent on what apps do. Since their global state is common, this can affect them in many ways. They even aren't allowed to have their own CLI args. A more flexible way would be vm.createInNewContext. And if apps do a lot of synchronous work, their performance can be unacceptable because they will block each other.

Answer (score 1):

Is this resource limited to 1 CPU? If so, then your best bet is making each task return an async function, and processing them with something like [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel).

Especially if your subtasks are broken down into mostly async functions, this will allow the tasks to run as "parallel" as possible.

In a multi-cpu environment, you can boost performance using child processes (or using native node cluster module). But, as others stated, this would require the memory overhead of v8 for each process.

If your tasks are mostly cpu intensive, you will not see much gain from the async.parallel, and it could even be slower than doing all your tasks sync. But, if there is network or disk access (IO), then using parallel should be faster.